# 'NSInvalidArgumentException' - [UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:] - unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I know this is dublicate question (and extremely sorry), but I've tried everything I've found on SO so far, but I am still receiving error this error:

> `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc4a9705960'`

Let me clarify the parts clearly with images, so we can produce a good answer for solving related problem.

This is the folder view (`ViewController` - main view, and `TableView1` is child):

[image]

My `TableView1.xib` file  has:

[image]  .  [image]

I have also edited my `TableView1.swift`:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
      return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
}
```

---

In my `Main.Storyboard`:

When I select `View Controller` [image] ([image]) it looks like this:

- 1. [image]
- 2. [image]

However, when I clicked on the `View` ([image]):

- 1. [image]
- 2. [image]

What am I doing wrong or missing on the way?

More Info:

[image]

[image]

Comment: who is owner of TableView1.xib, it must be TableView1.swift

Comment: What class is TableView1.swift? Probably the file in the .xib is supposed to be set to that class.

Comment: @vadian That's right. `TableView1.swift` and it's `.xib` should be the child of `ViewController.swift` & `Main.storyboard`

Comment: select tableview1.xib and locate owner on top left

Comment: @Alok, is it tableview.xib > File's Owner > and? . It's custom class > class is TableView1 and Module > Current..

Comment: now in attribute inspector there are some tabs (i am missing name). it looks like custom class, module same as you have attached in your question screen shot

Comment: @Alok tableview.xib > File's Owner > custom class > class is TableView1 and Module > Current..

Comment: can you just break connection in xib for data source and delegate, just break it and run see if crashes still

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95486/discussion-between-alok-and-senty).

Comment: I found another cause for this issue in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65619591/4995828).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]:
```

So as per the error log you have somewhere type mismatch when you set deletegate and datasource.Its happening because on xib you say the tableview1.xib should implement datasource and delegate.But in ViewController1.swift you are mistakenly referencing to UIViewController.
now you see UIViewController is just unknown about implementing delegate and datasource.As it dont find (obviously) it crashes.
so:

```
let controller : UIViewController = UIViewController(nibName: "TableView1", bundle: nil)
```

changed to:

```
let controller : UITableViewController = UITableViewController(nibName: "TableView1", bundle: nil)
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you call this function else where?

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
```

}

It looks like this function being called besides the delegate.

Comment: he is not calling it explicitly

Comment: that's right. I'm just calling it in `TableView1.swift` (as it's automatically created by New Swift Cacao Class

Answer (score 0):

No clue about Swift, but ObjC on iOS...

The Exception says that the class UIViewController can't handle the message [UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]. This indicates, that at some point, the dataSource is changed to "super".

Do you need the "override"? You're not overriding a message implementation, since UIViewController doesn't implement one.