# Unrecognised Selector when passing data between views

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, didselectrowatindexpath

Im currently trying to pass data to another view controller when a user selects a row within a tableView

The apps keeps terminating with an "unrecognised selector send to instance"

This is the code I'm using to pass the data to the other view, Yes the selectedUUID string exists in the view I'm trying to pass data to

```
    let data = self.journeyArr[indexPath.row]
    let uuid = (String(data.uuid))

    let Storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let JmvC = Storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "JourneyMessageViewController") as! JourneyMessageViewController
    JmvC.selectedUUID = uuid
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(JmvC, animated: true)
```

And this is the error im getting when I select a row in the table

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[LoopUltimate.JourneyMessageViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10950e430'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:\]: unrecognized selector sent to instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431013/tableviewnumberofrowsinsection-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya that post is about numberOfRowsInSection whereas im having issues with didSelectRowAt, Also that post is using Objective C.

Comment: **im having issues with didSelectRowAt**  --> You should check error message once. and there are many answer in swift

Comment: The error message you post shows **[LoopUltimate.JourneyMessageViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]** is the unrecognized selector. Is your `JourneyMessageViewController` a table view controller? Or does it have a table view in it? Does it implement `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`?